# add last custom collectionViewcell to collectionView swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to build collectionView with 2 different custom collectionviewcell. What I want is

[image]

Please ignore the first button (invite send one) We decided remove it. I only want to have plus button (add User one) at the end every time

I am getting error continue with many different approach that I found on google.
What I have is

```
import UIKit
import SDWebImage

private let reuseIdentifier = "safeCircleCell"
private let lastCell = "LastSafeCircleCell"

class SafeCircleCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

var circleArray: [CircleUser] = [];
var selectedEntry: CircleUser!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // TODO Need to add logic to add + button
    PackageGuardService.shared.getCircleUsers() {
        (circleUsers, error)in
        self.circleArray = circleUsers!
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
   collectionView?.register(LastSafeCircleCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: lastCell)
}
```

and .........

```
   override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    return self.circleArray.count + 1
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == circleArray.count {

        //try to set the add User button at the last cell

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: lastCell, for: indexPath)as? LastSafeCircleCell;
    //            cell?.btnLabel.text = "add friend"
        print("last Cell")
        return cell!
    } else {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)as? SafeCircleCell;

      // set all the user pic and info here and this part work great

            cell?.safeCircleImage.layer.borderWidth = 2
    cell?.safeCircleImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    cell?.safeCircleImage.layer.cornerRadius = (cell?.safeCircleImage.bounds.width)!/2
    cell?.safeCircleImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cell?.safeCircleImage.layer.borderWidth = 0.5

    let circleEntry = self.circleArray[indexPath.row]
    print("safe circle array image \(circleEntry.ImageUrl)")


    cell?.setUser(circleUser: circleEntry)

    return cell!
    }
}
```

and in my LastSafeCircleCell.swift file

```
 import UIKit

 class LastSafeCircleCell: UICollectionViewCell {
 let addCircleButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 18
    button.clipsToBounds = true
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "add-safe-circle"), for: .normal)

    return button
}()


let btnLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "add Friend"
    return label
}()
func addViews(){
    backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    addSubview(addCircleButton)
    addSubview(btnLabel)
}
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        print("lastCell in")
        addViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you please tell what is the error you are getting?

Comment: this is the error massage :    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier LastSafeCircleCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: Please try registering the class `LastSafeCircleCell` in `viewDidLoad` method instead of `viewWillAppear` method, you dont need to register the class each time the view appears

Comment: omg! Many Thanks! I got my last cell! but it only show black backgroundColor. Do you see any more wrong thing in my code for that??

Comment: actually I am trying to figure it out. no define frame size for button and label. I am getting it. Thanks a lot @stud1and3

Comment: Great, you are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is due to the fact that you are reloading the tableview before registering the class `LastSafeCircleCell` so I think you should register the class `LastSafeCircleCell` in `viewDidLoad` method instead of `viewWillAppear` method, and also because you dont need to register the class each time the view appears

Now to get the cell to show instead of black color, you need to set the frame of the `LastSafeCircleCell` either directly setting the frame or using Autolayout constraints and then set its properties like background color.

One more suggestion I would like to give is this:

Instead of

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: lastCell, for: indexPath)as? LastSafeCircleCell;
```

use this:

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: lastCell, for: indexPath) as! LastSafeCircleCell
```

I made two changes in the above code, you dont need to use `;` in swift if you are writing a single statement on a line. The second change that I made is to force unwrap the optional here using `as!` , this is one of the case where you want your program to crash if you dont deque the cell correctly.

so now in your following code you can simply use `cell` instead of `cell!` and do same for other cell in `else` part.